# concluding statement trouble:number guessing game python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement

The following code is for a simple number guessing game in python that I made.
The first version works flawlessly. But the second one, in which I have only modified the closing if statement causes the code following the statement to not run.Can anyone explain why?

Valid Code

```
from random import randint
tries = 0
secret = randint(1,10)
for tries in range(5):
    guess=int(input("Try to guess the number between 1 and 10 that 
    I'm thinking of."))
    tries+=1
    if guess<secret:
        print("Guess higher!")
    elif guess>secret:
        print("Guess Lower!")
    else:
        print("Whoa!You got it right!The number I was thinking of 
        was %s and you guessed it in %s tries."%(secret,tries))
        break
if guess!=secret:
    print("Sorry,you\'re out of tries.The number was %s"%secret)
```

Wrong code

```
from random import randint
tries = 0
secret = randint(1,10)
for tries in range(5):
    guess=int(input("Try to guess the number between 1 and 10 that 
    I'm thinking of."))
    tries+=1
    if guess<secret:
        print("Guess higher!")
    elif guess>secret:
        print("Guess Lower!")
    else:
        print("Whoa!You got it right!The number I was thinking of 
        was %s and you guessed it in %s tries."%(secret,tries))
        break
if tries>5:
    print("Sorry,you\'re out of tries.The number was %s"%secret)
```

Comment: Hum.. So what is your question ? Finding why the second is not working ?

Comment: Yes! Looks like I did'nt state it properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `range(5)` evaluates to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Therefore, `tries` is never greater than 5.

Comment: Oh!I get it.So i should write tries>4 instead of tries>5?

Comment: Not even that. Given that range(5) goes up to 4, your `tries` variable will end up with the value `4` in the end. Just `print` it to see for yourself...

Comment: @LightX Also, I don't know why you would mark as a solution an answer that's basically the same, except ~20 minutes later...

Comment: This is my first post on Stackoverflow..As a complete noob with a programming experience of one day,I felt that the second answer was more elaborate.If answering faster is the only criterion for marking an answer as solution,then I'm sorry.I hope you're satisfied by downvoting purely for that reason.Oh,and i did'nt know you could mark an answer as solution until Samer asked me..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were going for:

```
from random import randint
tries = 0
secret = randint(1,10)
for tries in range(5):
    guess=int(input("Try to guess the number between 1 and 10 that 
    I'm thinking of."))
    tries+=1
    if guess<secret:
        print("Guess higher!")
    elif guess>secret:
        print("Guess Lower!")
    else:
        print("Whoa!You got it right!The number I was thinking of 
        was %s and you guessed it in %s tries."%(secret,tries))
        break
    if tries == 5:
        print("Sorry,you\'re out of tries.The number was %s"%secret)
```

Since range will return values from 0 to 4, and hence the condition tries > 5 will never be met.

Comment: Kindly mark as solution if it helped get your code working.
Thanks

Comment: @LightX I don't have enough Reputation to comment on the answer above, but I just wanted you to know (for future purposes) that SO guidelines literally state the following "Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well." 

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if interested.